# "the same" or "same" in "Are they pronounced «»?"?

Tags: grammar, articles, definite-article

In the following sentence:

> These two words sound *the same* to me. Are they pronounced *the same*?

I wonder if I should write them as *the same* or *same*. I think it may be safer to write *in the same way* but sounds that it is a bit redundant.

So should I use the definite article or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the definite article. You would not write "those words sound in the same way to me"; it not just redundant, it's wrong.

> same **adverb**
>   B2 in the same way:
>
> We treat all our children the same.
>   I need some time to myself, the
>   same as anybody else.

[Same (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/same)

Comment: Thanks. In that case what is the part of speech of *the same*? I think *same* is an adverb, but how about *the same*?

Comment: Still an adverb.